# Which header file to include for ARM __sqrtf function?

Tags: c++, arm

I am thinking of using `__sqrtf` function in our product code. For that I wanted to measure its performance first against C math library `sqrtf` function. I wrote following code to quickly test.

```
#include<arm_neon.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
                float f = static_cast<float>(rand() / (static_cast<float>(RAND_M                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           AX / 100.0)));
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           w();
                float ans1 = sqrtf(f);
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           w();
                float ans2 = __sqrtf(f);
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           w();
                auto duration1 = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
                auto duration2 = duration_cast<microseconds>(t3 - t2).count();
                cout << duration1 << " " << duration2 << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the code using `g++ -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 test.cpp` on my Raspberry Pi 3, it gives error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/temp $ g++ -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 test.cpp
/tmp/ccK08ITT.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `__sqrtf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My Raspberry Pi 3 has VFP coprocessor I think.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/temp $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 2
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
```

Do I have to include some header file to use `__sqrtf`? This page does not mention it - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491e/CJAIFJIF.html

Comment: Where have you heard that there is a __sqrtf function that you can use ?

Comment: You absolutely certain you're using the ARM compiler? If you're compiling with GCC or clang, you're out of luck. Wait. Just found `g++ -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 test.cpp` in the question. You need a different toolchain.

Comment: @nos I found the function from here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491e/CJAIFJIF.html

Comment: Can you check what assembly does `__builtin_sqrtf` generate? Can you check if and how are `__FPU_USED` and `__CC_ARM ` defined?

Comment: @user4581301 I am compiling the code directly on Raspberry Pi. Which toolchain should I use?

Comment: Literally the ARM compiler from ARM. It is tuned to take advantage of ARM-specific magic. But before you drop a few thousand bucks, chase down @KamilCuk 's ideas. The GCC folks aren't stupid and may have alternatives.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://git.wise.ece.cmu.edu/adwait/pulsar_freertos/blob/bb0aef96c94b03a05dea01e47c576a23e530fcb8/pulsar_dw_restart_pps/CMSIS/arm_math.h#L5745) I think you can use `__builtin_sqrtf` on gcc, which should translate to `VSQRT` instruction.

Comment: I used `__builtin_sqrtf` and compiled the code using `g++ -g -O3 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 test.cpp -lm` and checked the assembly using `objdump -d -S a.out`. I don't see `VSQRT` anywhere in the assembly. Also, `__FPU_USED` and `__CC_ARM` are not defined.